# For Loop to convert string to list

Tags: r

I have a column in a data frame, which contains string values. I want to convert these values to lists of characters. When i try to execute the following code:

```
library(tidyverse)
col <- c("a,b,c,d","e,f,h")
df <- data_frame(col)
for (i in 1:length(df$col)) { 
    df$col[[i]] <- as.vector(unlist(strsplit(df$col[[i]],",")),mode ="list")
}
```

i get this error message:

```
Error in df$col[[i]] <- as.vector(unlist(strsplit(df$col[[i]], ",")), : more elements supplied than there are to replace
Traceback:
```

Is there a way to convert all the values in the column to lists ?

Thanks

Comment: That should be `data.frame` not `data_frame`. Moreover, what exactly do you want to be a list? The two dataframe elements, or every entry? Because your code would convert every single letter to lists.

Comment: @sedsiv `data_frame` is also a function in `dplyr`....It is not a typo

Comment: @Sotos I couldn't have known that he is using that package.

Comment: You have already your answer in your code : if you want a list of characters where each element is a letter just do : `as.vector(unlist(strsplit(df$col, ",")), mode = "list")`, if you want a list that looks like your tibble, just do : `strsplit(df$col, ",")`

Comment: If using `dplyr`, then `df %>% mutate(col = strsplit(col, ","))`?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, then this will do the trick:

```
rapply(df, list)
```